# Recursive function in python returns None

Tags: python, function, recursion, return

I have the following simple code to compute the sum of values until the indicated `number`. The total is stored inside `result`.

```
def ComputeMath(number, result):
   if number > 0:
       result = number + result
       print('if', result)
       ComputeMath(number-1, result)
   else:
       print("else", result)
       return result;

output = ComputeMath(5,0)
print(output)
```

For some reason `output` is always `None`. Printing it inside the function works fine. I just cannot figure out why this is happenning. Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: In the `if` branch you're _calling_ `ComputeMath()` but you're not _returning_ the result.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional split the code flow/execution among two paths but only one of them has a `return`, hence the other one will implicitly return `None`

```
def ComputeMath(number, result):
   if number > 0:
       result = number + result
       print('if', result)
       return ComputeMath(number-1, result)
   else:
       print("else", result)
       return result

output = ComputeMath(5,0)
print(output)
```

Here another possibility, a `return` for "all":

```
def ComputeMath(number, result):
   if number > 0:
       result = number + result
       print('if', result)
       ComputeMath(number-1, result)
   else:
       print("else", result)
   return result
```

Another way to look at the problem is not to print the output since the `print` is already in the body of the function.

```
def ComputeMath(...): # as in the question
   ....

output = ComputeMath(5,0) # the output maybe None
if output is not None:
    print(output)
```